# How to ensure execution of latest version of class file?

Tags: java

OK so I started with this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Oval extends Applet {
    public void paint (Graphics g) 
    {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(50,50,70,70);
    }
}
```

Saved it as Oval.java. Then I ran javac Oval and it spits out the class file. Linked the class file to my HTML and all was good. Then I tried to change the color of the oval to say Color.blue and everything was not so good. I just changed the code in the Oval.java file, then re-ran the javac Oval and the result was a "new" class file... but it's the output is the exact same.

Do I have to "reset" the memory space or something? I have tried for some time to get the answer but I simply lack the vocabulary to accurately ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the browser is caching the class file.  I would try

1. Running the applet using [the Applet Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppletViewer)
2. If that works, then it's a browser caching issue (clear your browser's cache)
3. But if it doesn't look different, or like you want in the Applet Viewer, then it must be something in your local environment (either it's not building the source file you want, or the class is going somewhere unexpected)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your browser is caching the previous version of your applet.  Try clearing / disabling your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the old version is in your browser-cache? Try hitting the follwing keys on your page:

- Windows: ctrl + F5
- Mac/Apple: Apple + R or command + R
- Linux: F5

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reset the java environment, ever.

You might have a browser window open, and your browser is attempting to be "smart" avoiding reload of a page which is already "fetched".  Depending on the browser, you will need to learn how to clear the browser cache.